# VisualVM fails to start

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, visualvm, jvisualvm

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10 VisualVM 1.3.9-1 cannot start.  It was installed through the package manager and I don't really want to install manually.  I tried opening it with logging like:

```
visualvm -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging-jconsole.properties
```

And it gives this output

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryFS.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryCacheManager.load(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.LayerCacheManager$1Updater.run(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.LayerCacheManager.store(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.ModuleLayeredFileSystem.setURLs(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.ModuleLayeredFileSystem.addURLs(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadLayers(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.access$000(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil$2.run(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.load(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Javas installed on the system are as follows

```
matthew@matthew-Kratos:~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
default-java               java-11-openjdk-amd64     java-8-openjdk-amd64
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-9-openjdk-amd64
matthew@matthew-Kratos:~$ dpkg-query -l | grep openjdk
ii  openjdk-11-jdk:amd64                       11.0.1+13-2ubuntu1                         amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-11-jdk-headless:amd64              11.0.1+13-2ubuntu1                         amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
ii  openjdk-11-jre:amd64                       11.0.1+13-2ubuntu1                         amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64              11.0.1+13-2ubuntu1                         amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-8-jdk:amd64                        8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1                 amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ri  openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64               8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1                 amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
ii  openjdk-8-jre:amd64                        8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1                 amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64               8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1                 amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
rc  openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64               9~b161-1                                   amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
```

Answer (score 3):

I get the same error with Debian unstable and `visualvm` 1.3.9 as well as 1.4.2.

The workaround that helped for me was to use the following (i.e. the same answer as provided by Tomas Hurka):

```
visualvm --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Of course, for this to work you need to install `openjdk-11-jdk`. Your path might need to be adjusted for your system; the idea is to run with a Java 9 or newer runtime.

(For reference, I think the underlying Debian bug in my case is https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897945)

Comment: Using JDK 11, I get: ```Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.activation not found``` (VisualVM 1.3.9)

Comment: Oh, I see - VisualVM versions prior to 1.4.2 don't run on Java 11: https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/108#issuecomment-418344988

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `VisualVM 1.3.9` on JDK 8. You can do it with:

```
visualvm --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Logging can be enabled with: `-J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true`

Comment: i tried both jvms.  same problem.  i have switched back to windows because latest ubuntu update messed up my dock

Comment: This gives me the same `NoSuchMethodError` as in the question.

Comment: Do you have VisualVM from https://visualvm.github.io ? It looks like visualvm from Debian is broken.